# Priority Version Number

Tags: version, priority-web-sdk

Is there a way to get the Priority Version number via the Web SDK or REST API?

Specifically I need to be able to know which side of a breaking change a particular version is at to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version by invoking loginFunctions.priorityVersion().

See here: https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/loginFunctions/#priorityVersion

Rest API will have a similar option in future priority version 22.0

Comment: That's great news for the Rest API, but it's not going to be backwards compatible is it.

Comment: As for the Web SDK function, from what version is it included?  Related, can I load the priority-web-sdk without the css?